# jQuery Selector Compare Expression

Tags: jquery

I copied this code from a web site and it achieves what I need, but can someone translate the syntax?

Many thanks for your help.

```
log.val(log.val() + ($('#defaultEntry').val() || 'blank') + '\n');
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#checkEmpty").click(function () {
            var log = $('#log');
            log.val(log.val() + ($('#defaultEntry').val() || 'blank') + '\n');
        })
    });
</script>

<p>
    <input id="defaultEntry" type="text" /></p>
<p>
    <input id="log" type="text" /></p>
```

Comment: copied it for what purpose? what are you trying to do?

Comment: That very first line isn't going to do a whole lot of anything outside of the `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I translated it into Mongolian for you. Hope it helps

```
  log.val (log.val () + ($ ('# defaultEntry') цэнийг () | | "хоосон") + \ 'N'.);
    <script>
         $ (бичиг баримт). бэлэн (функц () {
             $ ("# checkEmpty"). дарж (функц () {
                 VAR бүртгэлийн = $ ('# бүртгэл');
                 log.val (log.val () + ($ ('# defaultEntry') цэнийг () | | "хоосон") + \ 'N'.);
             })
         });
    </ скрипт>

    <p>
         үзсэн <Input id="defaultEntry" type="text" /> </ P>
    <p>
         үзсэн <Input id="log" type="text" /> </ P>
```

Comment: Considered up-voting simply for the humor. Reconsidered because now I have coffee all over my screen :)

Comment: You just made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from your question that this is the line that is confusing you:

```
log.val(log.val() + ($('#defaultEntry').val() || 'blank') + '\n');
```

If that is the case, basically what is happening here is that you are passing the `log.val()` function a string argument that is composed of a call to `log.val()` concatenated (`+`) with the value of `$('#defaultEntry')` **OR** `'blank'` plus a newline `\n` character.

In particular, this is the part to pay attention to:

```
$('#defaultEntry').val() || 'blank'
```

Basically what this says is that if the side of the expression to the left of `||` is *falsy* (i.e. `false`, `null`, `0`, `""`, etc.), then evaluate the expression to the right of the `||`, which in this case is the string `'blank'`. The effect of doing this is that, in the event that `log.val()` is empty, null, etc. your function will use the string `'blank'` instead.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Pls accept the answer so others will know :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { // execute the following after the HTML has loaded and the DOM is ready
        $("#checkEmpty").click(function () { // execute the following when the element with id="checkEmpty" is clicked
            var log = $('#log'); // assign the element with id="log" to a variable named 'log'
            log.val(log.val() + ($('#defaultEntry').val() || 'blank') + '\n');
            // take the concatenation of the current value of the element with id="log" (referenced by the 'log' variable)
            // with the current value of the element with id="defaultEntry" if not empty OR 'blank' (if the value of that element was empty)
            // and make that the new value of the element with id="log"
        });
    });
</script>
```